# How to read buffer path from variable in ssis?

Tags: ssis

While designing ssis package i gave buffer path as ("E:\ SSIS_Temp"). After configured i have deployed this package in another server. In that server no E: drive. In this case how to assign local buffer path for this package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a variable to hold the buffer path (in this example `file_storage_path`) and when you select a respective Data Flow Task, edit the Expressions from the properties list, as shown here:

[image]

After that, you can pass different parameter values depending on the execution location and method.

Comment: You are welcome, Dinesh. "This user has accepted an answer for 0 of 7 eligible questions" is something to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask